# My main activity is starts when i am go through login.but after login if i want to open it directly then it stops

Tags: android

### LogCat

The exception is the following one:

```
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 10784
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/com.clockerp.login.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:240)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at com.clockerp.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:99)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
03-17 11:06:09.497: E/AndroidRuntime(10784):    ... 11 more
```

> ### Main Activity is this
>
> in this the error is that when i again open the application it is unfortunatly stopped.
>   but if i logout then it start from login activity and run properly

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Student S;
    String    Id ;
    String Admiddion_no;
    String Firstname;
    String Midlename;
    String Lastname;
    String Dob;
    String Bloodgroup;
    String Gender;
    String Nationality;
    String Language;
    String religion;
    String Address1;
    String Address2;
    String City;
    String State;
    String Pin;
    String Phone1;
    String Phone2;
    String Country;
    String Category;
    String Admission_date;
    String Course_name;
    String Batch_id;
    String Batch_name;
    String Student_type;
    String Email;
    SharedPreferences pref;
   String username;
    String password;
    String domain;
    String type;



     @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    List prm = new ArrayList();
     //   SharedPreferences pref;
      //  Editor editor;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;


  //  private static String url = "http://mainerp.clockerp.com/webservice/student_info.php?";
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    LoginActivity l=new LoginActivity();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//       LoginDAO ld=new LoginDAO(getApplicationContext());
//       




        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();


        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
      ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_top, mDrawerList,
              false);

      mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Guardian Details
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Library
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // TimeTable
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Fee Details
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

//        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
//        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
                ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3c8dbc")));
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();


     pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
        l.editor =pref.edit();

        if (extras != null) {

           domain = extras.getString("domain");
            username = extras.getString("username");
            password = extras.getString("password");
            type=extras.getString("type");

            // and get whatever type user account id is
        }
       // domain=pref.getString(domain, "hello");

        prm.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));



       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),domain, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),type, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),password, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


       Log.e("himanshu","calling webservice");
       new  FetchStuentData().execute();


        ImageButton im=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.logout);
        im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.e("himanshu","logout button pressed");
                l.editor.putString("username", null); 
                l.editor.putString("password", null);
                l.editor.putString("domain", null);
                l.editor.commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully Logout !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
         });

       // Log.e("json response",S.getFirstname());


      // TextView title=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
      // title.setText(s);




    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item

            displayView(--position);
          //  view.setBackgroundColor(R.color.list_background_pressed);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
//             Log.e("himanshu","calling webservice in home");
//             new FetchData().execute();
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new GuardianDetailsFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new LibraryFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new TimetableFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
               fragment = new FeeFragment();
            break;
        case 5:

            Log.e("himanshu","logout button pressed");
            l.editor.putString("username", null); 
            l.editor.putString("password", null);
            l.editor.putString("domain", null);
            l.editor.commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
         break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
                ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3c8dbc"))); 

    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



    class FetchStuentData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

         /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
             Log.e("himanshu","checking");
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONObject json;


              // showAlert();
               try {

                  String finalurl =  "http://"+domain+"/webservice/student_info.php" ;

                 Log.e("himanshu",finalurl);
                    Log.e("request!", "starting");
                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                  json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                           finalurl, "POST", prm);

                        if(json!=null){

                             Log.e("json response",json.toString());
                             Log.e( "Response"," "+json.getString("religion"));
                               Id = " "+json.getString("Id");
                    Admiddion_no=" "+json.getString("Admiddion_no");
                         Firstname=" "+json.getString("Firstname");
                        Midlename=" "+json.getString("Midlename");
                         Lastname=" "+json.getString("Lastname");
                         Dob=" "+json.getString("Dob");
                        Bloodgroup=" "+json.getString("Bloodgroup");
                            Gender=" "+json.getString("Gender");
                    Nationality=" "+json.getString("Nationality");
                         Language=" "+json.getString("Language");
                     religion=" "+json.getString("religion");
                             Address1=" "+json.getString("Address1");
                         Address2=" "+json.getString("Address2");
                         City=" "+json.getString("City");
                         State=" "+json.getString("State");
                        Pin=" "+json.getString("Pin");
                       Phone1=" "+Integer.parseInt(json.getString("Phone1"));
                     Phone2=" "+json.getString("Phone2");
                     Country=" "+json.getString("Country");
                 Category=" "+json.getString("Category");
                  Admission_date=" "+json.getString("Admission_date");
              Course_name=" "+json.getString("Course_name");;
             Batch_id=" "+json.getString("Batch_id");
                  Batch_name=" "+json.getString("Batch_name");
                    Student_type=" "+json.getString("Student_type");
                    Email=" "+json.getString("email");

                    Log.e( "batch.",Batch_name);
                        }
                        else{

                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"emty json obj!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


           return null;  
        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted`

            TextView Stitle=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView Sname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.sname);
            TextView Sdob=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdob);
            TextView Sbloodgroup=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.sbloodgroup);
            TextView Sgender=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.sgender);
            TextView Snationality=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.snationality);
            TextView Slanguage=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.slanguage);
            TextView Sreligion=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.sreligion);
            TextView Saddress=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.saddress);
            TextView Scity=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.scity);
            TextView Sstate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.sstate);
            TextView Spin=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.spin);
            TextView Scountry=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.scountry);
            TextView Sphone=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.sphone);
            TextView Smobile=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.smobile);
            TextView Semail=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.semail);
            TextView Saddmisionno=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.saddmissionno);
            TextView Scourse=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.scourse);
            TextView Sbatch=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.sbatch);
            TextView Scategori=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.scateggory);
            TextView Stype=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.stype);

            TextView Saddmisiondate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.sadmissiondate);



            Stitle.setText(Firstname+Midlename+Lastname);
            Sname.setText(Firstname+Midlename+Lastname);
            Saddmisionno.setText(Admiddion_no);
            Saddmisiondate.setText(Admission_date);
            Sdob.setText(Dob);
            Sbloodgroup.setText(Bloodgroup);
            Sgender.setText(Gender);
            Snationality.setText(Nationality);
            Slanguage.setText(Language);
            Sreligion.setText(religion);
            Saddress.setText(Address1+Address2);
            Scity.setText(City);
            Sstate.setText(State);          
            Spin.setText(Pin);
            Scountry.setText(Country);
            Sphone.setText(Phone1);
            Smobile.setText(Phone2);
            Semail.setText(Email);
            Scourse.setText(Course_name);
            Sbatch.setText(Batch_name);
            Scategori.setText(Category);
            Stype.setText(Student_type);



        }      
    }

}
```

Comment: which code is there on line number 99 in LoginActivity.java

Comment: intent.putExtra("type", pref.getInt("type",2));

Comment: pl share code of your loginactivity

Answer (score 1):

You have the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

It means that you are trying to convert a String to an Integer.
To do so try this instead:

```
Integer foo = Integer.parseInt(bar);
```

`Bar` will be your `String`.

Since I don't see in your post the line of code you put in your comment, it's the best I can do.
Edit your question and point the line where the error occurs to get a more precise help.